# Cython/Python - Symbols not found PyString_Type

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am trying to call C++ code from cython and am following the [official guide](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html).

However, when importing the compiled module in python, I get the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ba16f97c2145> in <module>()
----> 1 import rect

ImportError: /home/userName/estCppLibrary/rect.so: undefined symbol: PyString_Type
```

I must add, that I have no admin permissions and had to install Cython locally in `~/.local/lib`. On my private laptop with sudo permissions and the default paths my code works.

Here is my code.

```
#setup.py

from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension

ext = Extension(
    "rect",
    sources = ["rect.pyx", "Rectangle.cpp"],
    language = "c++",
    include_dirs=["~/.local/include"],
    library_dirs=["~/.local/lib"]
    )

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(ext))
```

-

```
#Rectangle.h

namespace shapes {
    class Rectangle {
    public:
        int x0, y0, x1, y1;
        Rectangle();
        Rectangle(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1);
        ~Rectangle();
        int getArea();
        void getSize(int* width, int* height);
        void move(int dx, int dy);
    };
}
```

-

```
#Rectangle.cpp


namespace shapes {

Rectangle::Rectangle() { }

    Rectangle::Rectangle(int X0, int Y0, int X1, int Y1) {
        x0 = X0;
        y0 = Y0;
        x1 = X1;
        y1 = Y1;
    }

    Rectangle::~Rectangle() { }

    int Rectangle::getArea() {
        return (x1 - x0) * (y1 - y0);
    }

    void Rectangle::getSize(int *width, int *height) {
        (*width) = x1 - x0;
        (*height) = y1 - y0;
    }

    void Rectangle::move(int dx, int dy) {
        x0 += dx;
        y0 += dy;
        x1 += dx;
        y1 += dy;
    }


}
```

-

```
#rect.pyx

# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = Rectangle.cpp

cdef extern from "Rectangle.h" namespace "shapes":
    cdef cppclass Rectangle:
        Rectangle() except +
        Rectangle(int, int, int, int) except +
        int x0, y0, x1, y1
        int getArea()
        void getSize(int* width, int* height)
        void move(int, int)

cdef class PyRectangle:
    cdef Rectangle c_rect      # hold a C++ instance which we're wrapping
    def __cinit__(self, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1):
        self.c_rect = Rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1)
    def get_area(self):
        return self.c_rect.getArea()
    def get_size(self):
        cdef int width, height
        self.c_rect.getSize(&width, &height)
        return width, height
    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.c_rect.move(dx, dy)
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you can try using full path if you're sure that the file exists and the symbols required are in it.

Comment: My guess would be a mismatch between Python 2 (where `PyString_Type` exists) and Python3 (where `PyBytes_Type`) exists. Are you calling setup.py with the same version of Python as the headers for, and the same version of Python as the link libraries are for?

Comment: @DavidW Thanks! That did the job. I had python3 and python3.4 installed. The former I used for compiling, the latter was used by ipython/jupyter which I used to import the module. That caused the linking error.